# Is this object a random variable?

Tags: random-variable

Is the object $u$ which takes a value of 1 with probability $1/2$ and a value of $0$ with probability $1/2$ a random variable?

If not, what is the proper mathematical term for an object like this? Furthermore, what would be the random variable (+ probability distribution?) equivalent?

Comment: Not it isn't; was just curious about some terms I stumbled upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with parameter $p = 0.5$

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} p & \text{if }x=1, \\[6pt]
1-p & \text {if }x=0.\end{cases} $$

So in this case $u$ is a [random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-meant-by-a-random-variable) with sample space $u: \Omega \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$, that follows a Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: Is there any connection between this distribution and a random variable?

Comment: In your case $u$ is a random variable that follows Bernoulli distribution. If those terms are not clear refer to some statistics handbook for more details.